# AWS Glue - Creating ETL job flows using C# and Programmatic access

Tags: c#, ssis, aws-glue

Is it possible to create ETL workflows in aws glue using C# or dotnet code?
Or it is restricted to use pyspark and python only for creating job flows. Also is there a feature which allows to do lift and shift feature say using an existing ETL workflow in SSIS or informatica etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No they're not supported currently.  Only Python and Scala are supported.